# How to call function from another class?

Tags: java

I have two package:

1. java1 package with main class.
2. java2 package with end class.

I want to access function from end class to main class

java1 package - main class source code:

```
package java1;
import java2.end;

public class main extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public main() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    end.jTPanel();
}
}
```

java1 package - main class source code:

```
package java2;
public class end extends javax.swing.JPanel {

public end() {
    initComponents();
}

public static void jTPanel(){
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(1);//always error, jComponent in jPanel
}
}
```

can you help me?

Comment: Do you have an instance of `end`?

Comment: Instantiate `end` and then access methods from the instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the method `jTPanel` from `main` you need an instance of `end` in `main`.

In the `main` class before your constructor, create a new instance:

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    End myend = new End();
```

Then you can access the `jTPanel` method by calling:

```
myend.jTPanel();
```

**Side note: Java convention is to use capitalised class names. e.g. `Main` and `End` as apposed to `main` and `end`.**

Answer (score 0):

Make an instance of end class. Then using that instance call the methods of end class.

```
        end x=new end();
        x.jButton1ActionPerformed(event);
```